Isomorphism of set of formal concepts and a set of maximal bicliques.
Let $\mathcal{K}=(X,Y,I)$ be a formal context and $G=(U,V,E)$ be a bipartite graph. When a set $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ represents all formal concepts in $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{G}(G)$ represents all maximal bicliques in $G$, how can I define an isomorphism $f:\mathcal{B}(K)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(G)$?

Could you clarify this? Why should the bicliques be maximal and what is the structure of the set of maximal cliques?

A maximal biclique is a pair $\langle  C,D \rangle$ in a bipartite graph $G=(U,V,E)$, where $C\times D\subseteq E$, that cannot be extented to form another bigger biclique. And $G(\mathcal{G})$ is simply a set containing such pairs.

What sort of structure does the set max bicliques carry? If it’s just a set, what sort of isomorphism do you expect there to be besides just a bijection I.e a set isomorphism? Maybe you should start by thinking about what sort of structure you want to preserve in your map.

Yes, as you said, both $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ and $\mathcal{G}(G)$ are sets where each of which contains the same number of elements. I guess, based on your comment, simply one-to-one correspondence is enough to show that those two sets are the same.

Well the set of concepts forms a complete lattice. That’s why I was asking about structure of set of max cliques. If they both form complete lattices, then you can check if they are the same by considering a lattice homomorphism. What notion of homomorphism is correct depends on determining the amount of structure that the two collections have in common and then coming up with a map that preserves aspect of that structure.

Thanks. Constructing concept lattices is also the great idea! Forming a concept lattice from $\mathcal{G}(G)$ is indeed possible.
